# In Azure DevOps, logs display one of my SecureString parameters in plain text for an azure cli command

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

In my pipeline, I get secrets from my azure keyvault. Then I call azure cli to create/update a resource group using an arm json file with parameters.

Here are two pieces of copy/paste from the logs.

> "sendGridApiKey": { "type": "SecureString" },
> "serverAdminLoginPassword": { "type": "SecureString" }, "storageKey":
> { "type": "SecureString" }, "tokenSecret": { "type": "SecureString" },
> "twilioAuthToken": { "type": "SecureString" }, "twilioSid": { "type":
> "SecureString" }

> D:\a\1\s\src\MyProject.ResourceGroup>call az deployment group create
> -g MyRg --mode Incremental --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @azuredeploy.parameters.uat.json sendGridApiKey="***" tokenSecret="mySecretInPlainText" serverAdminLoginPassword="***"
> twilioSid="***" twilioAuthToken="***" storageKey="***"

We can see that my parameters are of type SecureString. Yet one of these always appears in plain text while the others are correctly hidden. I don't know if it helps to understand the problem but note that the secret in plain text has special characters like ; and * for example.

Update:
These variables comes from Keyvault.

[image]

Comment: are you getting the `tokenSecret` from key vault as well ?

Comment: It doesn't matter really what you define in the ARM template, Here you need to make sure this variable is defined as secret in azure devops.

Comment: I updated to show that all these variables come from Azure Keyvault.

Comment: I've seen pipelines do odd things in the past when they got different variables mixed up. Is there at any point a _different_ pipeline variable called 'tokenSecret', one which is not secret? Or is there at any point a different pipeline variable, not secret, which has the same value as (or a superstring or substring of) tokenSecret?

Comment: this is the only variable called `tokenSecret` in the whole pipeline. The secret is a very random and long string. No other variables is either a superstring or substring of it. The only difference between that variable and the other is that it is the first one in the list of the `secretFilter` input of the task `AzureKeyVault@2`

Comment: Could you share the revelant part of your pipeline please?